# C++ testing if callback is empty

Tags: c++, callback

I'm new to C++, I mostly use it for programming Arduinos and want to avoid adding multiple libraries --- space is limited.

I can't get testing for an empty callback to work. It compiles with G++, but fails on execution. The first part in main conducts a test and works, but the same test inside the class does not. The idea is to have a class that would use callback functions that are assigned specific to purpose.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef char* (*funct_ptr)(void);

char* func1(void)
{
        char *buffer = (char*)malloc((20)*sizeof(char));
        sprintf(buffer,"Function called");
        return buffer;
}

class TestClass
{
public:
        funct_ptr char_funct = nullptr;
        TestClass() {}
        char* get_str (void) {
                char *buffer = (char*)malloc((25)*sizeof(char));
                cout<<"Inside getv\n";
                if (char_funct != nullptr) {
//                         buffer=char_funct();
                        sprintf (buffer,"TBD");
                } else {
                        sprintf(buffer,"Empty in class");
                }
                return buffer;
        }
};

int main()
{
        funct_ptr afunc=nullptr;
        if ( afunc == nullptr ) {
                cout<<"Empty\n";
        }
        afunc = func1;
        cout<<afunc() <<endl;
        TestClass* test;
        char *buffer = (char*)malloc((20)*sizeof(char));
        sprintf ( buffer,"[%s]",test->get_str() );
        cout<<buffer<<endl;
        test->char_funct=func1;
        cout<<test->char_funct() <<endl;
//         cout<<test->get_str() <<endl;
}
```

Comment: You never create an instance of class `TestClass`, `test` is an uninitialized pointer. If you're working on a small MCU, get rid of all those mallocs, iostream, stay away from `new` as much as possible.

Comment: I missed the creating of the instance. I just tested the concept on PC to clarify it, iostream will not be present on the implementation. The rest will be reduced to the minimum.

Comment: you need to free `char *` in destructor

Comment: or somewhere else. it's np for test app to not have it but it'll be a problem in big app

Comment: I know about the rest, like freeing items. The question was not about optimization of the memory footprint and safeguarding against memory leaks, etc.

Comment: Once `test` is actually initialized, the code shown [seems to work for me](https://godbolt.org/z/f5f3548Tv).

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a `test` object pointer variable in `main` function which is pointing to a non-existing TestClass instance and could get any value according to stack state.

You need to create the object first either in stack or heap.

If you do below, it would be created in stack and will be destroyed while exiting from the function, e.g. main.

```
TestClass test;
```

If you'd like to create it in heap, you can do this one.

```
TestClass *test = new TestClass;
```

But you need to free that space with `delete test;` after it becomes useless. It wouldn't vanish by itself.

Suggestion: If you can get away with stack, always go with it and leave the heap alone.

As a side note, you would be getting SIGSEGV (Segmentation Fault) for these kind of errors and it will be the the one you'll see the most. It means you are trying to access a RAM area you shouldn't be accessing (out of scope).

Comment: As the answer @Mat said. It was an oversight. The cleaning up and all other comments are valid, but not the question that was asked.

Answer (score 0):

Once `TestClass` was initialized everything worked fine for me.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using Func = auto( * )( ) -> char*;

static auto func1( ) -> char* {
    char* buffer{ nullptr };
    if ( ( buffer = ( char* )malloc( 25 ) ) != nullptr ) {
        sprintf( buffer, "Function called" );
    }
    return buffer;
}

class TestClass
{
public:
    TestClass( ) noexcept
        : func_{ nullptr }
    { }

    explicit TestClass( Func func ) noexcept
        : func_{ func }
    { }

    auto get_str( ) const -> char* {
        if ( func_ ) {
            return std::invoke( func_ );
        }

        char* buffer{ nullptr };
        if ( ( buffer = ( char* )malloc( 25 ) ) != nullptr ) {
            sprintf( buffer, "Empty in class" );
        }
        return buffer;
    }
private:
    Func func_;
};

int main( ) {
    const TestClass test1{ func1 };
    const auto str1{ test1.get_str( ) };
    std::cout << str1 << '\n';
    free( str1 );

    const TestClass test2{ };
    const auto str2{ test2.get_str( ) };
    std::cout << str2 << '\n';
    free( str2 );
}
```